# Pdf-Lib: setText seem to not reading line break '\n'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

It seems like line break can't be properly read by pdf-lib

```
 const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBuffer);
 const form = pdfDoc.getForm();

 const attestorDetails = form.getTextField('AttestorDetails');
```

I tried

1.

```
attestorDetails.setText(
[`Liang Mula & Co.`, `Advocates & Co.`].join('\n'),
);
```

2. 

```
attestorDetails.setText(
`Liang Mula & Co. \nAdvocates & Co.`
);
```

I even tried

3.

```
attestorDetails.setText(
`Liang Mula & Co. \n \r Advocates & Co.`
);
```

but none of them worked

all I get is

```
Liang Mula & Co. Advocates & Solicitors
```

instead of

```
Liang Mula & Co. 
Advocates & Solicitors
```

what did I miss?

I tried

1.

```
attestorDetails.setText(
[`Liang Mula & Co.`, `Advocates & Co.`].join('\n'),
);
```

2. 

```
attestorDetails.setText(
`Liang Mula & Co. \nAdvocates & Co.`
);
```

I even tried

3.

```
attestorDetails.setText(
`Liang Mula & Co. \r\n Advocates & Co.`
);
```

Comment: Hi guys, if you were wondering how I solved this issue, I simply make the PDF input inside the template PDF to be "multiline" instead of just "singleline". You can search how to do it online. I am sure this won't solve everyone problems but some other people might. Thanks.